# Can BIOS record live USB usage?

Tags: linux, bios, liveusb

Say I have a live Linux distribution (e.g., Slax or Tails) on a USB stick.
Can a machine somehow memorize that such OS was used and when?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Are you asking specifically about the BIOS, or are you curious whether a computer in general could in theory record "live OS" usage, even if it was confined to removable media?

Comment: To further @bertieb's question - are you looking to take a "_screen capture_" of the session, or are you asking if the system records the fact that it booted from a USB device, possibly with additional information like the distribution?

Comment: Bios, No, UEFI, possibly.

Answer (score 2):

Is it *possible*?  Yes.  Is it *probable*?  No.

Although I dont *know* of any particular BIOS that records booting off USB in its logs, there is no technical reason it couldnt.  I also see that as a security feature that some would want, so I would think it would exist somewhere.  As for logging which OS was booted, that is far less likely, but still technically possible.

In terms of security and privacy, using a computer that is, or has been, out of your complete control is a risk.  You do not know what the hardware or software is doing.

Comment: My MacBook records in NVRAM the name of the last 10 distinct volumes it booted from. What other systems do idk but certainly some do.

Comment: @lx07 interesting. I did t know Macs did that. Well there is one example.